# Type: Badbox , Overfull \hbox for text

Tags: copy-paste

i get from external file ... xtras/intro.tex a badbox warning with the following

```
line 1   Overfull/hbox (54,60191 pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1---1
```

i copied and pasted text from word. I also just noticed that the text which should be about 5 lines long is contained within 1 line.

This is how it looks like....

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm=,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{setspace}           %   used for fine control spacing over line
\usepackage[]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{hyperref,appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\parindent=0cm
\sloppy
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}



\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE University Name}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large Major Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith} % Your name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. James \textsc{Smith} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\large \today}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage



\chapter*{abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline[]abstract}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}



\clearpage
\tableofcontents
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\listoftodos
\newpage

\chapter{Intro}

Commercial Near infrared spectrometers are expensive due to components such as diode array 
which can cost up to 13000 euro \todo{currencysymbol}. In this report,a designed Near infrared 
\todo{dash} spectrometer with a control system that will allow the users to do measurements in 
their desired near infrared \todo{dash} region and the device will be made user friendly. The 
following research questions will be covered:


\end{document}
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: i added the code and warnings. is there a way to post the pictures with no need for links..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the text below is actually an input. furthermore, other chapters commented out. After compiling, i get Overfull\hbox at the line where text starts ,  with '' !Undefined control sequence"    . BTW, my package has 31 lines, do u need to see them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sir, with the code above i get 4 warnings of  Overfull/hbox at line 130. If i understand it correctly, the copied text from word document as text margin wider than the width of the box.

Comment: OK finally:-) It still couldn't run as it was inputing a file that was not provided but I fixed that. [but look at the output!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c48Lu.png) it is just your todonote which does not fit in the small box, as presumably those notes are only in drafts you could just ignore it

Comment: `\center % Center everything on the page` is wrong it should be `\centering` (but centering all the document is very odd,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have disabled automatic hyphenation and are putting a long word into a very small box.

[image]

as it is just a todo note presumably in drafts you could ignore it or

```
\todo{cur\-rency\-sym\-bol}
```

produces

[image]

although still with some warnings.